# Port level traffic monitoring (with graphs)

Tags: monitoring, port, traffic

I'm looking to monitor traffic (incoming, outgoing and total monthly) on a few ports (mostly TCP) and I've done a ton of Googling around and everything leads to software I either can't manage to use, or I can manage to collect and graph data at the port level.

I currently have Zabbix installed and I can monitor traffic on an interface, but I haven't quite figured out how to on the port level.

I also have Ntop installed though I can't access the web gui just yet.

My main question is: Is the an 'almost out of the box' application that I can use to monitor traffic or has anyone had some luck with Zabbix and port level monitoring (or an integration of Ntop).

Note: Please don't mention Cacti.

Running CentOS 6 on KVM.

Answer (score 0):

Use iptables to allow traffic on the ports. It also does count amount of packets and bytes.

Then use iptables -L -n -v to display data:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
3530K  629M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

So, as you can see, there are pkts and bytes in the first two columns. :) You can also zero the counters - just use iptables -Z.

I think it'll be easy for you to find/write zabbix plugin.